# Как сделать секундомер в телеграм боте, с минутами и секундами

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Всем привет! Пишу телеграм бота, нужно чтобы при отправке сообщения выводило минуты и секунды, помогите пожалуйста!

````
from telebot import types


Token = ''

bot = telebot.TeleBot(Token)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    bt1 = types.KeyboardButton("Начать работу")
    markup.add(bt1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот, который поможет тебе быстрее печатать на клавиатуре.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def chat(message):
    if message.text == "Начать работу":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        bt3 = types.KeyboardButton("Практика")
        markup.add(bt3)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Выбери пожалуйста режим", reply_markup=markup)
    elif message.text == "Практика":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Легко")
        markup.add(btn1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Выберите уровень сложности", reply_markup=markup)
    elif message.text == "Легко":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Вернуться")
        markup.add(btn1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="бабочка багреный балагур балка бежевый водица водяной ")
    elif message.text == "бабочка багреный балагур балка бежевый водица водяной":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Молодец, ты печатал это  .... минут  .... секунд')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Неправильно,попробуй еще раз")
bot.polling(none_stop=True) ```
````